# How to create IBAction for object created in class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*) settingsButtonForController:(UIViewController*) viewController{
    UIBarButtonItem* settingsButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle@"Settings"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
        target:self
        action:@selector(doSettings:)];
    //...customize appearance of button
    return settingsButton;
}

-(IBAction) doSettings:(id)sender{
    //...the functionality for the settings button
}
```

I'm trying to create an action for a button that I am creating in a class method, but Xcode tells me that actions are required to be instance methods. Is this possible with some modification, or do I have to give in and make my button-generating method an instance method?

the viewController here is one that I would like to populate my "settingsButton" with programmatically. "settingsButtonForController" is in a UIGenerator class that I made

Comment: what is the purpose of the `viewController`?

Comment: Of course it has to be an instance method. Static methods are defined to be universal across all instances of a class. However, view controllers in your storyboard are **unique**, and therefore are **instances** of a given class. Hooking up a static method just makes no sense in this case. Why don't you want to hook them up to instance methods?

Comment: it is part of a UIGenerator class that I created so that I could have one location to customize buttons, etc. that should appear in multiple controllers throughout my app

Comment: Just pass the `target` as a parameter. Also note that `UIAppearance` is far better for appearance customization and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: @Sulthan good suggestion of UIAppearance. I will have to try it sometime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define `doSettings:` in `viewController` and make it public. 
and when creating button:

```
 UIBarButtonItem* settingsButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle@"Settings"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
        target:viewController
        action:@selector(doSettings:)];
```

i assume that this `viewController` may be different view controllers in your project inheritedFrom `UIViewController`.
you should define `doSettings:` in all subclasses of `UIViewController` that you call this static method.